# How can I reset a user password for a VMware Fusion guest installation of Snow Leopard Server?

Tags: virtualization, osx-snow-leopard, vmware-fusion, macos-highsierra

I would like to change a user password for a guest installation of Snow Leopard Server.

I've looked around, and found that one proposed solution was to hold Command-S after the chime. I tried several times, and never had it boot any differently.

I have the installation disk, and it's a guest on OSX High Sierra.

**--EDIT--**

Thanks to @Tetsujin's kind help, I got in Single User Mode.

Kind of.

But if this is Single-User Mode, it's the most noop of a Single-User Mode I've seen in any Unix. The text appears clipped, although that's tolerable; what I don't understand is that none of the commands generate any output besides the shell giving another prompt.

I started to try to mount the filesystem to change the password, but this seems a broken Single-User Mode. Is there anything else I should be doing to get a Unix command line?

[image: Single user mode screenshot]

Comment: Is this a password for the VMWare app [I use Parallels, so not sure of VMW's setup], or just one of the user accounts in OS X? If it's user, then why not just use the users & groups panel?

Comment: It's the (one) regular user account that I presently need to log in normally.

Comment: Then do it from the Users & Groups pref pane... or do you not know the existing password?

Comment: I do not know the existing password. That is why I want to reset it.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question - Cmd/S is VMWare's 'take snapshot' so will override Single User unless you change the key commands in prefs. Answer added.

Comment: maybe see - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61905/how-can-i-reset-a-macs-password-from-single-user-mode

Answer (score 0):

From [VMWare KB - Switching Mac OS to Single User Mode](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004018)

> To switch into Single User Mode:
>
> Note: Single User Mode significantly limits the functionality of the
>   operating system. You do not have access to any portion of the normal
>   Mac OS graphical interface. VMware recommends that you only use Single
>   User Mode if you have experience with the operating system and already
>   know how to use this Mac OS feature.
>
> 1. Shut down and then power on the
>      computer.
> 2. Immediately press and hold Command + S.
> 3. Release Command + S
>      when you are at a shell prompt.
>
> Note: To leave Single User Mode type exit and press Enter.
>
> If you are
>   attempting to start up a Mac Server OS virtual machine in Single User
>   Mode, Command + S attempts to take a snapshot of the virtual machine.
>   Therefore, you must remap Command + S to be sent a different key
>   stroke.
>
> You can remap a different key combination on the host Mac to send
>   Command + S to the virtual Mac. Shift + Command + S is already
>   assigned, but Option + Command + S is a valid alternative.
>
> To remap the keys:
>
> 1. Open Fusion.
> 2. Go to VMware Fusion > Preferences >
>      Keyboard & Mouse > Key Mappings.
> 3. Click the + button to add a shortcut.
> 4. Under From:, select Option, Command, and S (from the dropdown).
> 5. Under
>      To:, select the Windows key and S (from the dropdown).
>
> Note: In newer versions of Mac OS X, you need to type S in the right
>   text field.
>
> 6. Click OK.
> 7. Close the Preferences window.
> 8. Shut down any open virtual
>      machines.
> 9. Quit and reopen Fusion.

Comment: Thank you; I got into Single-User Mode but encountered difficulties (see screenshot and additional information in edited question). Now I'm scratching my head at Single-User Mode's behaviour.